# App inspection does not detect any devices

Tags: android, android-studio

android studio version:
[image: android studio]

pc:

[image: pc]

problem:

I'm running the app on an emulator (pixel 4 API 28), however no process appears here, tried uninstalling the app on the device, cleaning the cache, wiping the data from the emulator and cold booting, nothing changed. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Happend to me couple of times... restarting the computer works for me idk why

Comment: Just did that, nothing changed unfortunately...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of updating android studio uninstall and install newly because Android SDK is corrupted sometimes or some file are missed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly which sdk tool fixed it, but after I update some sdk tool, This issue gone away both app inspector and layout inspector.

In Andorid studio open File -> Appearance and behavior -> System setting -> Android SDK -> SDK tools tab and update ...

This is some sdk tool which i have update

- SDK command-line tools Latest 9.0
- Android auto api simulators
- Android platform tools
- Layout inspector image sever for api 29-30(It's for layout inspector)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue as well but I solved this...

**The solution I used is :**

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and restart

I hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: tried that many times before, no results unfortunately